# $r(S+T)\le r(S) + r(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and $S$ and $T$ are linear transformations from $V$ to $V$, how can you show that $\text{im}(S+T)$ is a subset of $\text{im}(S) + \text{im}(T)$ and also that $r(S + T)$ is less than or equal to $r(S)+r(T)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $dim(im(S)) = s, dim(im(T)) = t$ and their respective basis $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_s\},\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_t\}.$ can you see that $im(S+T)$ is generated by the union of the two sets of the basis? it implies $dim(im(S+T)) \le s+t.$

to see an extreme case set $T = -S.$

Comment: But what if for some $i$, $x_i$ is equal to $y_i$?

Comment: @dhk628, that is why the $dim(im(S+T))$ can be less than $s+t.$